# Neo4j answer for congress

Tags: neo4j

I am having trouble figuring something out. I am trying to make a neo4j question that answers: "How many laws were presented on the 114th congress, and how many of these are currently active?".

Currently, this is my clause:

```
MATCH (b:Bill {active:"True"})-[r:PROPOSED_DURING]->(c:Congress {number:"114"})
RETURN count(b) AS count
```

Now all I am missing is the amount of ALL the bills that were presented during this congress, even if they are not active now.
Now I am currently only showing the bills that are currently active, but I would also like to show ALL the bills(even if they are inactive now) that were proposed during this congress. I got a hint that this clause is successfully answered with the

```
SIZE
```

function, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SIZE() to get the count of instances of a graph pattern. And there are some additional optimizations we can look for.

If the :PROPOSED_DURING relationship only connects :Bill nodes to :Congress nodes, then you can use SIZE() to get the degree of the relationships on the :Congress node without having to actually traverse the relationships:

```
MATCH (c:Congress {number:"114"})
WITH c, size(()-[:PROPOSED_DURING]->(c)) as totalProposed
MATCH (b:Bill {active:"True"})-[:PROPOSED_DURING]->(c)
RETURN totalProposed, count(b) as activeProposed
```

Note that we are able to get the degree of the relationship because we aren't requesting any information (labels, properties) on either the relationship itself, or on the node at the other end of the relationship. If we had done this instead: `size((:Bill)-[:PROPOSED_DURING]->(c)) as totalProposed` then it would have required traversal of the relationships and filtering of the label on the node at the other end, which would be a bit more costly. If other types of nodes other than :Bill can be :PROPOSED_DURING a congress, then there is no choice but to go this route, however.

Comment: Thank you very much, and thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you were unable to use the `SIZE` trick provided by @InverseFalcon's answer (e.g., if multiple node types can have `PROPOSED_DURING` relationships to a `Congress`), here is a more direct query that should still work:

```
MATCH (b:Bill)-[:PROPOSED_DURING]->(:Congress {number:"114"})
WITH COLLECT(b) AS proposed
RETURN
  SIZE(proposed) AS totalProposed,
  REDUCE(s = 0, b IN proposed |
    CASE b.active WHEN 'True' THEN s + 1 ELSE s END) AS activeProposed;
```